# sum details from two different group with condition in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am very new at crystal report and need help to display following and I hope this is not too complicated

Here is my table:

```
id amount comment    status
A     100 principal  paid
A      10 interest   paid
B     200 principal  outstanding
B      20 interest   outstanding
C     300 principal  outstanding
C      30 interest   outstanding
```

Currently this is group by comment crystal report showing this:

```
principal   
A     100 
B     200 
C     300 
Total 600   

interest    
A     10 
B     20 
C     30 
Total 60
```

I would like this to be displayed when status is 'outstanding', principal display sum of principal and interest. When status is 'paid' just showing principal amount

```
principal   
A     100 
B     220 
C     330 
Total 650

interest    
A     10 
B     20 
C     30 
Total 60
```

I tried to do sum with group by in SQL expression but crystal report give me return more than 1 value error

Any help very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the Group section for 'Principal' (using section suppress expression).

Instead, insert a CrossTab (Report Header) and set row to be 'ID' and 'Amount' as value to sum. Or, if you want even more flexibility, you can insert a subreport.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try the first suggestion but would you please expand on the insert a subreport please

Comment: I may have missed something here as I cannot get Cross Tab to work. It works for B and C but wont work for A as it should only have principal amount (not principal + interest). I am struggling with sub report as essentially I am stuck with the same original problem

Answer (score 0):

A subreport would allow you to show the result of grouping your data in a way that is not limited to how the main report is grouped. A CrossTab allows you to do the same but is not as flexible in terms of layout (grid only), content, selection criteria (must be same data set as main report or the main report group it's located in), etc.

Comment: this is interesting. i have very limited knowledge on these, subreport or crosstab. happy to have a read on subreport. would you be able to let me know good reading for building subreport and how it works?